# How to close one window using Control D/Z without exiting the whole program (multithreaded java socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Screenshot of program running (top left: server, the rest are clients):
[image]

In the bottom-right window, I am trying to press Control D (mac) (for windows it's control Z) in order to exit **the bottom right window/client alone** without exiting the entire application/program but it doesn't seem to be working because I can still type "it didn't work" and it outputs the message.

**My question is:** What changes can I make to the following code so that when a client presses Control D it will close just one window/client and not exit the whole application?

Part of code that should close the window (currently empty):

```
          //This is the code that prints messages to all clients
          synchronized (this)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
            {
              if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("null") && !line.equals(null) && !line.equals("F") && !line.equals("m") && !line.equals("M") && threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null && !threads[i].clientName.equals("m") && !threads[i].clientName.equals("M")) 
              {
                if(!line.equals("") == true && line.isEmpty()== false)
                {

                      threads[i].os.println(name + ": " + line);
                }

             }
            //After Control D/Z is pressed, this code will execute
              else if(line.equals(null) || line.equals("null") || line.contains("null"))
              {
                  try
                  {
                      //This code location exits the program, system.exit(0) and system.exit(-1) didn't work
                      //how do i close only one client window here without exiting the whole program?
                  }
                  catch (NullPointerException ignored)
                  {

                  }
                  finally
                  {

                  }
                 // threads[i].os.close();
                 // System.exit(0);
              }
            }
          }
```

**NOTE: SKIP THE REST and scroll down if you already know the answer**

Full code of ClientThreads.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
class ClientThreads extends Thread
{
  public String path = "";
  public String name1 = "";
  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final ClientThreads[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;
  public int position = 0;
  public static List<String> listName = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  public String[] namesList = new String[10];
  public ClientThreads(Socket clientSocket, ClientThreads[] threads, 
          String name, String[] namesList, List<String> listName)
  {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
    this.name1 = name;
    this.namesList = namesList;
  }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run() 
  {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    ClientThreads[] threads = this.threads;
    synchronized (listName)
    {
        //Iterator i = listName.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block

         ListIterator<String> i = listName.listIterator();
    }
    try 
    {
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      String name3;
      while (true) 
      {
        //os.println("What is your name?");
        name = is.readLine().trim();
        name3 = name;
        break;
      }
      synchronized(listName)
      {
        if(!listName.contains(name))
        {
                    if(!listName.contains(name) && name != null && !name.isEmpty())
                    {
                        listName.add(name);

                        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
                        path = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                    }
        }

      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this)
          {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null)
          {

          }
        }
      }
      while (true)
      {
        synchronized(listName)
        {   
        }
        String line = is.readLine();

        if (line.contains("3582938758912781739713asfaiwef;owjouruuzlxjcjnbbiewruwoerpqKFDJiuxo9")) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {   
        }
           synchronized (this)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
            {
              if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("null") && !line.equals(null) && !line.equals("F") && !line.equals("m") && !line.equals("M") && threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null && !threads[i].clientName.equals("m") && !threads[i].clientName.equals("M")) 
              {
                if(!line.equals("") == true && line.isEmpty()== false)
                {

                      threads[i].os.println(name + ": " + line);
                }

             }
              else if(line.equals(null) || line.equals("null") || line.contains("null"))
              {
                  try
                  {
                      //This code location exits the program, system.exit(0) and system.exit(-1) didn't work
                      //how do i close only one client window here without exiting the whole program?
                  }
                  catch (NullPointerException ignored)
                  {

                  }
                  finally
                  {

                  }
                 // threads[i].os.close();
                 // System.exit(0);
              }
            }
          }
       // }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this && threads[i].clientName != null)
          {
          //  threads[i].os.println(name + "has disconnected.");
            threads[i].listName.remove(name);
            listName.remove(name);
          //  threads[i].os.println("The list now contains: " + listName);
           // System.out.println("A user disconnected. The list now contains: " +listName);
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] == this) 
          {
            //threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
     // is.close();
     // os.close();
      //clientSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
  }


}
```

Full code of ChatClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatClient implements Runnable 
{
  public static String path = "";
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  private static DataInputStream is = null;
  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;
  public static String[] namesList = new String[10];
  public int iteration = 0;
  public static String[] responses = new String[50];
  public int responseCount = 0;
  public static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  public static final ClientThreads[] threads = new ClientThreads[maxClientsCount];
  public static List<String> listName = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
 public ChatClient()
 {

 }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

     for(int i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++)
     {
         namesList[i] = "";
     }
     for(int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++)
     {
         responses[j] = "";
     }
    // System.out.println("args[0] is: " + args[0]);
    int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    String host = "localhost";
    //int filePort = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    try 
    {

        synchronized(listName)
        {
             clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
             inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        }

    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      //System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
     // System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
       //   + host);
    }
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
    {
      try 
      {

        new Thread(new ChatClient()).start();
        while (!closed)
        {
          os.println(inputLine.readLine() );
        }

       // os.close();
        //is.close();
        //clientSocket.close();

      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
       // System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run()
{
    String responseLine = "";
    try 
    {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
      {
          if(responseLine!=null && !responseLine.equals(null) && responseLine!="null" && !responseLine.equals("null") && !responseLine.contains("null"))
         {
              System.out.println(responseLine);
         }

         else if(responseLine.contains("null") || responseLine.equals("null") || responseLine==null || responseLine.equals(null))
         {

             //This is another location which will be executed if Control D/Control Z is pressed
             //os.close();
            // is.close();
             //System.exit(0);
         }


      }
      //closed = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    //  System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Full code of ChatServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ChatServer
{
  public static List<String> listName = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  public static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  public static Socket clientSocket = null;
  public static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  public static final ClientThreads[] threads = new ClientThreads[maxClientsCount];
  public static String[] namesList = new String[10];
 // public ChatClient arrayOfNames = new ChatClient;


  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      synchronized (listName)
        {
            //Iterator i = listName.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block

             Iterator<String> i = listName.listIterator();
        }
      int once = 0;
      if(once == 0)
      {
        //  System.out.println("args[0] is: " + args[0]);
          int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
         // System.out.println("waiting for connections on port " + portNumber + " ...\n ");
          once = 3;
      }
      once = 3;
    try 
    {
      int portNumber1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) 
    {
      try
      {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;


        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
            if (threads[i] == null)
            {
                String name = "";
                (threads[i] = new ClientThreads(clientSocket, threads, name, namesList, listName)).start();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == maxClientsCount)
        {
          //PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
       //   os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
        //  os.close();
        // clientSocket.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: it might also be possible to change threads[i] to threads[i+1] in order to keep track of different clients in certain parts of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need instead of this:

```
while (!closed)
{
  os.println(inputLine.readLine() );
}
```

is this:

```
String line;
while ((line = inputLine.readLine()) != null)
{
    os.println(line);
}
```

This will fall-through when ctrl/d or ctrl/z is pressed, as appropriate, and `main()` will then exit. Provided you have also made your threads daemons, the JVM will then exit.

NB this:

```
// After Control D/Z is pressed, this code will execute
```

isn't true, and this:

```
else if(line.equals(null) || line.equals("null") || line.contains("null"))
```

is drivel. `line.equals(null)` can never be true, by definition, otherwise a `NullPointerException` would have been thrown instead of calling `.equals()`: and why you should be interested in whether the user has typed "null", or something containing "null", is a mystery.

And why you are using `synchronized(listName)` in the `main()` method of an application which up to this point is single-threaded is another mystery.